# XHTML doctype template for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I create a new file on npp its just a blank document, can I make it generate an html doctype strict/transitional like how dreamweaver does with the premade templates?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using macros:

1. Press **Start Recording** button on Notepad++ toolbar:
   [image: start]
2. Open a new document
   [image: new]
3. On the newly opened tab, **TYPE** your template code (type code, don't paste it)
   (e.g.: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`)
4. Press **Stop Recording** button:
   [image: stop]
5. Save your just recorded macro:
   [image: save]
   assign a keyboard shortcut if you want:
   [image: save macro]
6. Run macro from menu or invoke it by keyboard shortcut you assigned on save, whenever you want to create a new template-based document:
   [image: run macro]

Also you can open as many template-based documents as you want, by selecting option **Run a Macro Multiple Times** from **Macro** menu:
[image: open multiple documents]

[image: results]

That's it. I hope this info will be helpful for you.

Comment: Ideally this should make BODY, etc tags too but you can just add those into the recording steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple plugin called "NewFileBrowser" which you can find using Plugins>Plugin Manager. 
It will set up two templates for you that you can use for your boilerplates. Actually the default value it comes with are an html 4.01 template and a java class.

Configuring it is quite easy to figure out. Once installed it gives you a menu item under Plugins>NewFile&Browser>Create New File which will open a new document with your boilerplate contents in it.

It's perfect if, like me, you only need it for new html documents.